# How check if checkbox is checked? And how sum a value?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

In a code like this, for example, how can I check if the checkboxes were checked and show an alert with the values’ sum? There will be more checkbox than those two.

```
<ion-list>

<ion-item>
<ion-label>Pepperoni</ion-label>
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]=“pepperoni” value=“3.5”
<ion-item>
<ion-label>Sausage< /ion-label>
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]=“sausage” value=“4.2”</ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>

<ion-row center>
<ion-col text-center>
<ion-button click=“getValue()”>Value<ion-button>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: You want to check if they're checked inside of your page or inside of your page module? In both cases you can just check if the ngModel is true, if it is true, the checkbox is checked. p.s. you can't save a value in a checkbox element as you're doing. the unique values of a checkbox is true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<ion-content padding>


<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let entry of form">
    <ion-label>{{entry.val}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox slot="end" [(ngModel)]="entry.isChecked"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>


<button ion-button (click)="getValue()">Value</button>


</ion-content>
```

**TS**

```
public form = [
      { val: 'Pepperoni', isChecked: true,value:'3.2' },
      { val: 'Sausage', isChecked: false,value:'4.2' },
      { val: 'Mushroom', isChecked: false,value:'5.2' }
    ];

getValue(){

  let checkedControls = this.form.filter(result=>result.isChecked==true);
  let sum = 0;
  checkedControls.forEach(result=>{
    sum = parseFloat(result.value) + sum;
  });

  alert(sum);
}
```

**Working demo**:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-icvos9